# UX Builder not loading for product description edits

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have a wordpress site running the Flatsome theme with WooCommerce activated. Everything worked fine on localhost, but then I uploaded it to a live server (ubuntu running Apache2). The UX Builder will not load when I try and edit a product description in wp admin. After I click "Edit with UX Builder" the page stops loading after a few seconds and shows a blank white page.

Firefox gives the following error in the console:

"The resource at “https://www.mysite.co.zw/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/packages/woocommerce-admin/dist/components/style.css?ver=1.8.3” preloaded with link preload was not used within a few seconds. Make sure all attributes of the preload tag are set correctly."

On Chrome it gives me this error in the console:

"The resource "https://www.mysite.co.zw/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/packages/woocommerce-admin/dist/app/style.css?ver=1.8.3" was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally."

Please note UX Builder works when editing other pages, it is JUST when I try and edit product descriptions. Not sure what might be causing this or how to go about fixing it? Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you have a `<link rel="preload"` tag for that stylesheet that isn't actually included on the current page. WooCommerce does generate these itself, in the Loader class maybe_output_preload_tag, so it sounds like there's a bug there: either in WooCommerce or in the Flatsome or its UX Builder's interaction with WooCommerce. As a work around for now you can probably just edit woocommerce/packages/woocommerce-admin/src/Loader.php to never output preload tags, but if this is specific to your UX Loader you should ask its authors for support.

Comment: Do you also have a plugin that combines and minimises CSS and JS, e.g. an auto optimize plugin? This might also be the culprit, if it's combining the CSS into a separate file and no longer using the version WooCommerce is trying to preload.

Comment: @Rup Nope I don't have any plugin that combines and minimizes CSS and JS. I also tried disabling all the plugins (except woocommerce) and the problem still persists. I have sent an email to the theme author. Thanks very much for your above suggestions.